# Speed of an object using android app

Tags: android, android-sensors

I know that we can measure the speed of an android device using the inbuilt sensors.

Now is it is possible to measure the speed of a moving object using an android app.

I have seen the speed gun app in the play store.I want to know how the app works.

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, stick the object to the device (or viceversa) and move the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

If device has GPS module, yes, it can measure the speed of the device relative to Earth.